# Need help to make a portable LED light based on the LM3421

Tags: led, pwm, driver

I am trying to make a portable LED light based on the [LM3421](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3421.pdf?ts=1647920838656&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM3421). I would like to use it in buck boost mode.

- Input voltage from 4s battery-- 12 to 16.8
- LED voltage - 14.4
- LED current - 3A
- PWM frequency of 20kHz
  Is the LM3421 good for this task?

My main doubt is whether the LM3421 will deliver the same voltage when the battery voltage varies between 12V and 16.8V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a current regulator so it should deliver the same *current* for that range of input voltages. That will be about the same voltage, but it will change a bit  depending on LED die temperature etc.

The topology shown in example *9.2.2 LM3421 Buck-Boost Application* should work for you, but you'll have to work through the detailed design for your higher LED current and narrower input voltage range.

You'll likely also want to add battery protection to shut the circuit down before the battery voltage falls so low that the battery is damaged.